How to prevent the escaping of ampersands when copying elements from DevTools
I'd like to copy the source for several elements from some dynamically-generated web pages. Using the Elements panel in DevTools to do the copies gets me so far, but the entire output has ampersands escaped, even inside attribute strings.
For example, an image element:
<img class="someclass" src="https://somesite.com/images/aguid?w=200&h=300&id=mypic" />

copies as:
<img class="someclass" src="https://somesite.com/images/aguid?w=200&amp;h=300&amp;id=mypic" />

I've tested using the current versions of Chromium-based browsers like Edge and Chrome, and also Firefox, but the Copy functionality always escapes, even if I copy from the console or directly in the source view.
Note: this doesn't seem to occur for other characters which are normally escaped for HTML display, such as < and >.
I assume the underlying reason is that DevTools is itself a web page and ampersands must be escaped to be displayed, but it seems counterintuitive to not restore the original text when copying to the clipboard.
Unfortunately, I can't just download the raw HTML page because the elements are dynamically generated. (This is actually why I'd like to extract the element source in the first place, to document the generation process.)
Is there a straightforward method of extracting the verbatim content? I don't mind installing an extension if necessary.

Online tool. https://www.urldecoder.org/

@GetSet Thanks, but DevTools isn't URL-encoding the attribute strings, otherwise the ampersand would be translated to a %26.
The HTML encoding for ampersands occurs for all attributes, by the way, not just src.

I see. My mistake. Its doing html special chars. Different online tool --> It'll decode the ampersands and leave the rest intact thats not already encoded. https://onlinephp.io/htmlspecialchars-decode  ... Im not too familar with the dev tools copy problem and am suggesting an online tool as a workaround as opposed to creating your own, although the latter was my first thought.

It's how outerHTML is serialized per the specification, devtools just uses it as-is. See What characters must be escaped in HTML 5?

@wOxxOm Sorry for the late reply. I thought ampersands were escaped if they were ambiguous, i.e. if there's a semicolon later on in the string and they could be misinterpreted as representing a character constant. It looks like the dev tools always escape them, even if they are unambiguous.

My point is that the same happens when running $0.innerHTML, so devtools simply uses that without any change. You may argue the browser is bugged.

@wOxxOm Maybe 'overly conservative' would be a kinder phrase for me to use :) I can certainly understand the desire to err on the side of caution and always escape the character.
Thanks for your help.
